# How do I use/enable zcache?

Tags: 13.04, kernel, ram

I'd like to try out zcache but I just can't figure out how I would enable it, do I have to compile a new kernel with zcache enabled?   I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 64bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, I just added `zcache` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub` file, then ran `sudo update-grub`.

**Example:**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash zcache"
```